# MvvmLight dynamic message token

Tags: mvvm-light

Is it possible to send register for a Message that is created with a dynamic token?

I have several user controls that are in a ItemsControl and I want each control to only listen for messages that target a certain Id.

Keeps throwing a un-handled exception.

Comment: If you post a code snippet, you will have better luck getting an answer.

Comment: Could you also specify what you mean by "dynamic token".

Answer (score 0):

Please see the video of Laurent Bugnion, who has developed the mvvm-light toolkit:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03

He is saying about a universal lambda converter in this discussion.